# How can I reduce render time on scenes with lots of UI component?

Tags: rendering, unity

I'm looking for a way to reduce rendering time for my Game Over scene. A quick look of the scene components is like this:

[image: GameOverScene Mockup]

All yellow objects are UIButton, texts are all UIText, white areas are all UIImage (including the background). The friend list is a Facebook friends list contained inside a Scroll View. All object are inside a Canvas that resizes to the camera.

I noticed the problem firsthand when playing the game on Android. This game over scene is running at 15fps (while the main game play scenes are all running at nearly 60fps). The phone is a HTC One. On my cheap LG phone the game simply crashes at this scene.

Profiler shows Camera.Render() taking 70~90% of each game loop.

The iPhone5 & 6 on the hand is quite interesting, fps show no real difference between gameplay scenes and the gameover scene, both running smoothly at ~120fps. Still Camera.Render() was taking 40~50% of each loop in GameOver scene vs ~20% on GamePlay scenes.

Quite strange considering the fact that HTC One specs and iPhone 5's are quite similar.

I think the problem is because of the large number of UI Components on the GameOver Scene, since sprites on gameplay scenes are all batched (it's a 2d game). So I suppose I must find a way to reduce draw call on all those UI components. I thought this should be a common problem, but strange enough I've been searching for weeks without a sounding solution that actually work.

- I've tried to check all UI objects static: doesn't show any notice-able change. On the other hand, Scroll View's contents are what's taking the bulk of the rendering (a long friend list), and I can't mark them as static because they do move.
- Canvas pixel perfect off: already done that from the beginning.
- Move the Scroll View to a separate Canvas: only improve performance when I'm actually scrolling scroll view, otherwise no change. And - could be I did something wrong - the scroll view doesn't work on Android anymore.

**TL;DR; Question**: Please guide me to reduce rendering time on scenes with lots of UI elements.

Comment: How many friends you are getting? Secondly if you share some code then we can discuss further

Comment: Hello, at the beginning there's a fake friend list with 7 items, and that's what I'm profiling on. Actual friend list length depend on the number of user's friend playing the game. Let's imagine it would be Facebook's maximum friend limit of 5000 because my game surely will become the next Flappy Bird like every game made by newbies for the last 2 years :)   I could surely share my code but it's mostly drag&drop in Unity Editor, so I don't know how to share.

Comment: It is really very difficult to figure it out in limited information because i believe that there would be something else causing the problem. Well, it could be image size, image materials using what shaders, so on...

Comment: I keep hearing people complaining about UI and preferring GUI. I'm one of them. Just saying. :)

Comment: Hello @NikaKasradze, do you mean [this GUI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html). I didn't know it would be possible to this to create game UI. Do you have a link to detailed information? (since Unity docs is terrible)

Comment: @HamzaHasan Hmm I'll think about a way to share the scene. Quite complicated considering how Unity use so much drag & drop. I'm not using any material or shader for my images, and they're all at native size. (the only thing that scale is the Canvas Scaler fit to camera width)

Comment: Then only thing is to be consider the size of images. Are they large in size? Btw @NikaKasradze is right :)

Comment: So um after a while figuring out I can pin down the problem to items inside a scrolling friend list not being batched. The screen was having 38 draw batches, 30 of which are created by the scroll view. Each item in the list add 4 more draw calls. I was trying to reproduce the problem on a new project so I could share, but they turned out batching smoothly even when I just simply copy the entire thing over as prefab. Any speculation what might be causing this?

Comment: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v386/AVAVT/Somanydrawcall_zpsry533gtm.png sum up my problem